# blueimp jquery upload SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, json, image-uploading, blueimp

I'm using the jquery library blueimp upload.
I want to upload images to a different directory.
I just modified the /server/php/**index.php** file (only this file) :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require_once('UploadHandler.php');

//$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
define(DIR_DOWNLOAD, "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/villalba2");
define(HTTP_SERVER, "localhost/villalba2");

$blogId= "Mobiliario";
$upload_handler =   new UploadHandler(array(
            'upload_dir' => DIR_DOWNLOAD . '/uploads/' . $blogId. '/',
            'upload_url' => HTTP_SERVER . '/uploads/' . $blogId. '/', 
));
```

the permission folder are 777

The images are loaded correctly in the directory that i want, but I get this error:

Chrome ->SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
Safari ->SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

The result of /server/php/**index.php** is:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant DIR_DOWNLOAD - assumed 'DIR_DOWNLOAD' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/villalba2/up/server/php/index.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant HTTP_SERVER - assumed 'HTTP_SERVER' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/villalba2/up/server/php/index.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />


{"files":[{"name":"cama (1).jpg","size":101775,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/cama%20%281%29.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/thumbnail\/cama%20%281%29.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=cama%20%281%29.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"cama (2).jpg","size":101775,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/cama%20%282%29.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/thumbnail\/cama%20%282%29.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=cama%20%282%29.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"cama (3).jpg","size":101775,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/cama%20%283%29.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/thumbnail\/cama%20%283%29.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=cama%20%283%29.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"cama.jpg","size":101775,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/cama.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/thumbnail\/cama.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=cama.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"mantelera.jpg","size":50986,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/mantelera.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/thumbnail\/mantelera.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=mantelera.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"test (1).png","size":15,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/test%20%281%29.png","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=test%20%281%29.png","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"test (2).png","size":15,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/test%20%282%29.png","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=test%20%282%29.png","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"test.png","size":15,"url":"localhost\/villalba2\/uploads\/Mobiliario\/test.png","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/villalba2\/up\/server\/php\/?file=test.png","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

Why dosen't work?? the images are upload  in the correct folder :S

Thanks!

---THIS  LAST PART IS SOLVED-----

Edit:

Now the the thumbs are not displayed on the browser..

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `/localhost/villalba2/up/localhost/villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/thumbnail/mbiliario.jpg`

the correct absolute path it will be:

/localhost/villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/thumbnail/mbiliario.jpg

the path:
/localhost/villalba2/up/  is where is the blueimp jquery upload core

Comment: can you post lines 15-17 ? from index.php

Comment: yes, , sorry , i just edited

Answer (score 1):

You must use quotes when you define a constant

```
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/villalba2");
```

Then the json output will be parsable

Comment: Thank!!, now works, but the images are not displayed

Answer (score 1):

In order to [define constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) they must be quoted in the definition -

```
define("DIR_DOWNLOAD", "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/villalba2");
define("HTTP_SERVER", "localhost/villalba2");
```

Comment: Thank!!, now works, but the images are not displayed

Comment: If the errors are gone then we can start looking at what is going on to prevent them from being displayed. You may want to edit your original post.

Comment: Are the images uploaded to the correct folder? If so the display issue may be another question because we have solved the error from this question @berti

Comment: Yes , the images are uploaded correctly, but in the browser aren't displayed.
the URL is worng . I edit  my post

Comment: NOW i solved. i edit define("HTTP_SERVER", "localhost/villalba2"); to  define("HTTP_SERVER", "/villalba2");

Answer (score -1):

change

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
```