# blueimp jquery upload SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: cakephp, blueimp, image-upload

I'm using [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload images in cakephp 2.x. Images are upload but issue is after uploading images.I got error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and json data in html format. I tried to figured it out myself and find a solution given on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804480/blueimp-jquery-upload-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-solved). I tried to resolve my issue by following answer given in solution but could not. (sorry for bad English)
my controller code

```
App::import('Vendor', 'UploadHandler', array('file' => 'file.upload/UploadHandler.php'));
        $this->layout = 'upload';
         $options = array(
       //     'upload_dir' =>  WWW_ROOT . DS . 'img',

            'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',                    
           );
        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
    }
```

I changed url In main.js(blueimp js file)

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'index'
});
```

json data displayed on index page.

```
 {"files":[{"name":"1186225_383357368459160_1371777554_n.jpg","size":58938,"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/files\/1186225_383357368459160_1371777554_n.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/files\/thumbnail\/1186225_383357368459160_1371777554_n.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/?file=1186225_383357368459160_1371777554_n.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"},{"name":"e0775308650b201469fc68765dc4ff7a.jpg","size":150919,"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/files\/e0775308650b201469fc68765dc4ff7a.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/files\/thumbnail\/e0775308650b201469fc68765dc4ff7a.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/ec\/cakephp\/app\/webroot\/?file=e0775308650b201469fc68765dc4ff7a.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

Comment: How should anyone be able to troubleshoot this? There's not even a `<` in the JSON that you've posted!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
it was the validate variable

wrong

```
public $validate;
```

correct

```
public $validate = array();
```